# Enable Gnome Classic from the command line?

Tags: gnome, vnc, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-classic

I've installed `gnome-shell-extensions`, but I'm on VNC, so can't follow the normal instructions for logging in and selecting 'Classic' in the login  menu (there isn't a login menu). For TigerVNC, X is run from `/etc/X11/Xtigervnc-session`, but it's not at all obvious (to me) how Gnome is run from that point.

Background: I'd like to get something close to the desktop I see on RHEL8 (also on VNC). RHEL uses plain Gnome 3, but it defaults to a usable classic desktop, so I'd rather not install Mate/whatever to get back to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, most of which don't seem to work. The Red Hat admin guide ([here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/what-is-gnome-classic#gnome-classic-switch) for RHEL 7 - the RH docs are always a good place to look) gives these commands to switch from GNOME classic to GNOME (first) or the other way around (second), in a running session:

```
$ gnome-shell --mode=user -r &
$ gnome-shell --mode=classic -r &
```

The second one almost worked for me on 22.04, but Gnome crashed after a few seconds (over vnc; all my systems are headless). If it works, it should give a good way to (non-permanently) see what Classic looks like, though.

`tigervnc` runs `/etc/X11/Xtigervnc-session`, which runs  `/etc/X11/Xsession`, which sources the scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`. These read various envvars which should set the session for you. In particular, they should read `~/.gnomerc`, and I think adding these to `.gnomerc` should start Classic:

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-Classic:GNOME
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic
```

But, again, I couldn't get this to work (on vnc). Note that your `~/.xsessionrc` probably contains

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
```

which you may or may not have to remove or comment out.

Finally, you can actually set the session in `tigervnc` itself (this one works). Create a `~/.vnc/tigervnc.conf` containing:

```
$session = "gnome-classic";
```

the session must be one of the ones listed in `/usr/share/xsessions` (for 22.04, I have `gnome-classic`, `gnome-classic-xorg`, `ubuntu`, and `ubuntu-xorg`; I have no idea what `gnome-classic-xorg` is).

Finally - logging out to test stuff is difficult on vnc. It's easier to ssh in and bring the runlevel down to 3 and then back up to 5:

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
# systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

you can run `runlevel` after each command to confirm that the runlevel has gone from 5 to 3, and then from 3 to 5. You can run up your vnc viewer again after doing this.

Comment: I'm curious. Maybe whoever downvoted this could tell me what the correct answer is.